# How to get query string parameter from SEO-friendly URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I switched from using normal URL parameters to SEO-friendly URLs. For example, I have gone from this...

```
http://www.example.net/mypage.aspx?id=1
```

... to this:

```
http://www.example.net/mypage/1
```

Using JavaScript or jQuery, what would be the best way to get the id variable of 1?

I currently use a function like this:

```
// get the values from the query string.
function GetQueryStringParams(sParam) {
var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);

var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');

for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
        return sParameterName[1];
    }
}
```

Is there a better way or am I stuck splitting the URL via the `/?`? And how would you handle multiple parameters?

http://www.example.net/mypage/1/2/3/4/5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest would probably be

```
var sPageURL = window.location.href.split('/').pop();
```

Comment: That's a very good answer. And it works in this situation. However problems may arise in the future if I use more than 1 variable. Thanks.

Comment: Then you'd have to write code that gets those variables based on where in the URL they are. There is no magic function.